# Problems Encountered Trying to Vertically Stretch a Scaled Bold Smallcaps Title in a Usual Way

Tags: titles, small-caps, scalerel

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{scalerel} % For Vertical Stretch
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Allows to make bold the smallcaps text.

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{textbf}
{\scalefont{1.5}{{\scshape{This is a Title \\[5pt] with bold smallcaps; \\[3pt] {\large{though,}} \\[16pt] Not Vertically Stretched}}}}
\end{textbf}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

I would like to vertically stretch all of the words in the title by a factor of, say, 1.5. However, I have tried inserting `\vstretch{1.5}` with proper nesting at various places within the coding of the title, but all to no avail.

QUESTION: How may the above code be modified in order to vertically stretch the given title by the said amount?

Thank you.

Comment: `\begin{LARGE}` is sort of OK although you should end the paragraph before `\end{LARGE}`,  `\begin{textbf}` is _weird_ as `\textbf` takes an argument, so `\begin{textbf}abc\end{textbf}` is `{\textbf{a}bc}` and will just make `a` bold.

Comment: `\slshape` and `\large` do not take an argument so `\slshape{...}` should be `\slshape ...` and similar;y `\large{...}` should be `\large ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not show the usage of `\vstretch` that you tried and did not work, perhaps you got the nesting confused due to the unauthodox grouping used in the original, especially `\begin{textbf}` which would group and apply bold to just the following token.

Also the `scalerel` commands are basically for math mode, you could use a nested `$` to get back to text but it is simpler to just use a standard `\scalebox` here as in the second form below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{scalerel} % For Vertical Stretch
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Allows to make bold the smallcaps text.

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\bfseries\scshape
%\LARGE\scalefont{1.5} 17*1.5 = 25.5 \huge is 25
\huge
\vstretch{1.5}{$This is a Title$}\\[5pt]
\vstretch{1.5}{$with bold smallcaps;$}\\[3pt]
{\large{though,}} \\[16pt]
\vstretch{1.5}{$Not Vertically Stretched$}
\end{center}

\bigskip


\begin{center}
\bfseries\scshape
%\LARGE\scalefont{1.5} 17*1.5 = 25.5 \huge is 25
\huge
\scalebox{1}[1.5]{This is a Title}\\[5pt]
\scalebox{1}[1.5]{with bold smallcaps;}\\[3pt]
{\large{though,}} \\[16pt]
\scalebox{1}[1.5]{Not Vertically Stretched}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

So I didn't use either the `scalerel` or `scalefnt` here (just the implicit loading of `graphics`)

Comment: Many thanks, again for your help. Sorry about not showing where I had placed the `\vstretch`s. There were several, but I could have shown at least one.